# SharePoint 2013 Query for specific content type

Tags: search, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to get the Search Content Web Part to display an aggregation of announcements from various announcement lists in a site collection.

I created the announcement lists using the "add an app" then "Announcements" so I am assuming that this is a list of the ContentType Announcement? I've added a new announcement to the list with a title of "this is a test".

After I have added the Search Content Web Part to a page (for test purposes a page in the same site as the announcement list) and gone to set the Query on the web part to:

```
ContentType:0x0104*
```

No results are being returned. To check that the announcement has been indexed by the crawler changed the query to:

```
Title:this is a test
```

Now two results are displayed 1 a csv and the other the announcement with a ending with ../DispForm.aspx?ID=1 .

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ContentTypeId. I know that by default ContentType is shown this way, but it might be a bug. Just try ContentTypeId.